# One call back stores a workspace variable, need another callback function to read it (MATLAB GUI)

Tags: matlab

I have a variable (my_data) being added to the workspace by the following callback:

```
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
results = firstStepFunction;
export_name = 'my_data';
assignin('base',export_name,results);
```

I have another callback which I would like to use my_data and plot a histogram using the function velHistFunction:

```
 function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 velHistFunction
```

where velHistFunction looks like this:

```
function figure = velHistFunction(my_data);
numOfBins = 120;
[freq, xOut] = hist(my_data(:,1), numOfBins);
figure;
bar(xOut, freq/sum(freq)*100);
set(gca,'fontsize',20)
xlim([0 7]);
ylim([0 max(freq)/sum(freq)*100]);
end
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem with velHistFunction or the way I've set up the pushbutton4 callback... thanks

Comment: You are calling `velHistFunction` in `pushbutton4_Callback` with no input. Again, see MATLAB's documentation for [sharing data among callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html).

Comment: Perhaps handles can be used to hold user data and to share among different call backs